# Does sdl support ARM lcd video display?

Tags: linux, video-streaming, arm, sdl, lcd

am new to SDL and I have used the spcaview code to get video stream from a camera to a FriendlyARM LCD but the video display is not good and moves very fast. It however works well on the computer screen. I was wondering if SDL supports LCD display; if yes what am I missing?. If no, what can I do because I need to stream video from a camera to an LCD device. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, SDL supports LCD display. I think its the difference in the Computer system and that of the ARM lcd that caused the results I had. Am still working on it; will update this once I find the solution.
Cheers.